# Автоматизация скриншотов веб страниц

Tags: веб-программирование

Здравствуйте, господа.

Есть около 500 ссылок в текстовом файле, надо сделать скриншот каждой страницы.
Как автоматизировать?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Скрипт создания скриншотов](http://live-code.ru/page/delaem-skrinshot-sajta-php-skript) ([вариант №2](http://blog-kota.ru/skript-dlya-skrinhotov.html)), ну и запустить в цикле

Answer (score 1):

Можно взять утилиту делающую снимки (webkit2png, khtml2png, и т.п.) из командной строки и прогнать ее по всем ссылкам.

Comment: ещё можно firefox заставить